# Why Error 415 with Axios when CURL works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, ecmascript-6, axios

If I do

```
curl -s -d "username=test&password=test" -X POST https://example.com/api/jwt/login
```

then I get the expected token. If I do

```
const axios = require('axios')

async function getToken() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('https://example.com/api/jwt/login', {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      params: {
        username: "test",
        password: "test"
      }
    })
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
getToken()
```

then I get

```
Error 415 Unsupported Media Type
HTTP ERROR 415
Problem accessing /api/jwt/login. Reason:
Unsupported Media Type
```

## Question

Can anyone figure out why it works with `curl` and not with `axios`? What am I doing wrong?

## Update

The following gives same error

```
const qs = require('query-string');

async function getToken() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('https://example.com/api/jwt/login', {
      method: 'post',
      params: qs.stringify({
        username: "test",
        password: "test"
      })
  })
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments for `axios.post` are `url[, data[, config]]`. See [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config). Your example passes the following to the `data` argument, which will be the request body:

```
{
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  params: {
    username: "test",
    password: "test"
  }
}
```

The server cannot parse this or is parsing it incorrectly so returns `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

What you will need to do is separate out your request body and config. Your request body will also need to be [encoded](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format).

```
axios.post(
  'https://example.com/api/jwt/login',
  qs.stringify(({
    username: "test",
    password: "test"
  }),
  {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you can't pass in a javascript object, it needs to be parsed.

You can do this using the `URLSearchParams` API in JavaScript, or using the `qs` package. You also need to use the `data` key instead of the `params` key in the payload:

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const qs = require('qs')

async function getToken() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      'https://example.com/api/jwt/login',
      qs.stringify({ username: 'test', password: 'test' }),
      { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} }
    )
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
getToken()
```

You can find documentation outlining this on the axios github here: https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Comment: Wing's answer worked, where he didn't have `data`. I suppose that is the only difference?

Comment: URLSearchParams worked for me without having to add any new package

Answer (score 0):

try using querystring module to enocde data

```
npm install query-string
```

and then

```
const qs = require('query-string');
//...    
data: qs.stringify({
username: "test",
password: "test"
}),
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

Comment: sorry, typo... please try `data: qs...` instead of `param: qs...`

Comment: found this post: https://flaviocopes.com/axios-urlencoded/